# How to correct Status Code:400; Error code: Malformed Policy

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation, aws-cli

```
Unknown field version (Service: Amazon S3;       
Status Code: 400; Error Code: MalformedPolicy;   
Request ID: VKA1M3MNY37B2DGN; S3 Extended        
Request ID: UItdX5yp9vy6KB19HQVjBdkW1fyGh2EvZ+47 
Y1KcQ03WExKAqRVJivrw+4cQns6OXo7ax8lwO2Y=; Proxy:                                                                                                                                                         null)
```

```
BucketPolicy:
Type: AWS::S3::BucketPolicy
Properties:
  PolicyDocument:
    Id: MyPolicy
    Version: '2012-10-17'
    Statement:
      - Sid: PublicReadForGetBucketObject
        Effect: Allow
        Principal: '*'
        Action: "s3:GetObject"
        Resource: !Join
          - ""
          - - "arn:aws:s3:::"
            - !Ref MyWebsite
            - /*
  Bucket: !Ref MyWebsite
```

I receive the error message above when I deploy my bucket policy.

When I use the yaml lint site it says format is fine but when I use the CLI `sam validate --lint` command I get this message:

> /Users/travissalmon/Desktop/Web Development/Resume Challenge/cloud-resume-challenge/template.yaml is a valid SAM Template

Not sure what to do.

Answer (score 1):

I tried this template and it worked with no issues for me.

```
sam validate: success

sam deploy -g: success
```

This is the script I used.

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: "2010-09-09"
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: Test Code

Resources:
  BucketPolicy:
    Type: AWS::S3::BucketPolicy
    Properties:
      PolicyDocument:
        Id: MyPolicy
        Version: "2012-10-17"
        Statement:
          - Sid: PublicReadForGetBucketObject
            Effect: Allow
            Principal: "*"
            Action: "s3:GetObject"
            Resource: !Join
              - ""
              - - "arn:aws:s3:::"
                - !Ref MyWebsite
                - /*
      Bucket: !Ref MyWebsite

  MyWebsite:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
```